# What is a good introduction to category theory for computer scientists?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science

I am looking for an introduction to category theory for computer scientists.

- I have no background in category theory, or advanced math such as topology.
- I am interested in logic, and applications to computer science (theorem provers, performance guarantees of programs, etc). I've heard that category theory is relevant for these topics.
- I would like the introduction to be concept and intuition-heavy, and not unnecessarily over-technical.

Comment: Maybe https://www.amazon.co.uk/Categories-Computer-Science-Cambridge-Texts/dp/0521422264/

Comment: Also [Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/basic-category-theory-computer-scientists) by Benjamin C. Pierce

Comment: The book that they teach here at our cs department is: [Steve Awodey's Category theory](http://angg.twu.net/MINICATS/awodey__category_theory.pdf) This book has many examples, and almost none of them require advanced math(but knowing math would not hurt). He literally defines groups for one of his examples i think.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a good start is the book Category theory for scientists by David Spivak. It does not require any advanced math.

http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp13/CT4S--static.pdf

Answer (score 2):

How about [Category Theory for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/)?